# Why array parameters are infered as union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I define a custom hook to get the url parameters as follows:

```
const useUrlQueryParam = <K extends string>(keys: K[]) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParam] = useSearchParams();
  return [
    useMemo(
      () =>
        keys.reduce((acc, cur) => {
          return { ...acc, [cur]: searchParams.get(cur) || "" };
        }, {} as { [cur in K]: string }),
      [searchParams]
    ),

    (params: Partial<{ [key in K]: unknown }>) => {
      const o = {
        ...Object.fromEntries(searchParams),
        ...params,
      } as URLSearchParamsInit;
      return setSearchParam(o);
    },
  ] as const;
};
```

When I try to use this hook like

```
const [param, setParam] = useUrlQueryParam(["name", "personId"]);
```

I assume the generic type `K[]` now becomes string[], but actually it is `useUrlQueryParam<"name" | "personId">(keys: ("name" | "personId")[])`

I don't understand why is that?

Comment: Because `extends string` is a marker for the compiler to infer narrow literal types instead of the wider string. Why use `K extends string`  and not just `keys: string[]` if you don't care about the narrow literal types passed in ?

Comment: Typescript has several of these markers, you ca check out my tweet and video on this topic https://twitter.com/TitianCernicova/status/1504146863318093828?s=20&t=xVLhq82jki-ehFa9RFt29g

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir Thanks for your helpful comment.`K extends string` means I want the passed params to be string, and the returned value is something with a type like what I have passed in `{name: string, personId: string}`

Comment: Then I don't really understand the question. What is the problem ?

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir To make the return object with a type as { [cur in K]: string }  I have to use generics K[], and to make sure passed in parameters are strings  I have to use `K extends string`, that's why I did this.

Comment: Is there any actual problem you have with your code, or are you just wondering why `K` is a union of literals?  If you do have a problem, please spell it out, explicitly, in the text of the question.  If not, then @TitianCernicova-Dragomir has answered that question, and if you have any outstanding question, then again, please spell it out in the question.